# Iterate over JSON passing time variables to URL in Python

Tags: python

I’m 2 days into Python and am having to tackle this. Any guidance or framework is appreciated.

I can see plenty of examples to read from JSON and load an object etc but did not stumble across something where the URL will take time variables and iterate

My url takes a starttime and end time in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format. It return a Paginated event log JSON data for that timeframe. There is a Page_of Field ( total number of pages), and page field ( num of pages returned) and a events element that contain list of fields. Only events that contain data for the events will be included in the response.

My goal is to iterate over the URL for a 5 min timeframe and write the fields to a pipe delimited CSV file that is moved to another location. End time becomes start time in the next iteration and keep this process going.

I need basic approach and syntactical guideline on efficient ways to approach this.

Regards
Siva

Comment: 1) Write code that calculates a timeframe. 2) Write code that fetches the URL with the timeframe. 3) Write code that transforms the JSON to CSV. 4)  Write code that appends to the CSV file.